# Why do we use a softmax activation function in Convolutional Autoencoders?

Tags: convolution, image-recognition, autoencoder, activation-function, softmax

I have been working on an image segmentation project where I have created a convolutional autoencoder. I saw this image and implemented it using Keras.
[image: Deep Autoencoder]

At the output layer, the author has used the softmax activation function. Shouldn't it be ReLU?

> According to me, this seems to be a regression problem, where we need
>   to predict the continuous values for the segmented image pixels. If so, why are we using a softmax function, instead of ReLU or a linear function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the images, it seems an **image segmentation problem**. As you see, the Autoencoder is not returning a more or less accurate representation of the original input image, but *the segmentation of it*. Each of the output colors are segments of the image that have been classified. Probably the classes are something such as: "road", "tree", "building", "sky", etc.

In other words, it's an Autoencoder performing a classification task. That explains the softmax layer at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Since its a multi-class classification problem, each class will have its own probability value between 0 and 1 and sum of all probabilities of classes will equal to 1.